# Word for a person who just talks but would not do what he/she says

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word which describes a person who just talks but would not do or practice what he/she says - like somebody who doesn't practice what he/she preaches.

Comment: You could also describe that person as "not putting their money where their mouth is." In any case, it is a form of [hypocrisy](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hypocrisy), so they would be some kind of "hypocrit" (hypocritical person).

Comment: The word you are looking for is "hypocrite", but there are many [synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/hypocrite). We expect users here to do self-research and include some context and example sentences when they ask a question about single word request. Please visit Help Center to read the guidelines. Good luck.

Comment: More context is needed. If you mean someone who fails to live up to moral or ethical principles, then the suggestion of hypocrite is correct. But if you mean someone who fails to live up to more worldly talk (e.g. "I'm going to make a million dollars by the time I'm thirty!" or "my mousetrap is going to take the world by storm!" but really they just sit on the couch and play video games/watch TV) or more practical promises ("I'll take you to the zoo next weekend, son" but they never do because they're "too busy") then a different term might be better.

Comment: On a lighter note, in the context of religion and/ or politics, such persons are called "priests" or (more accurately) as "politicians"

Answer (score -1):

In our country we have a saying called "Ja Baas" 
It is in Afrikaans, and lightly translated it means "yes person". 
Which obviously does not sound the same in English.

Comment: It would actually translate as 'yes, boss'.

Comment: Actually, a "yes man" is not really like the person described by the OP, IMO.  A yes man just agrees with whatever their boss says to curry favor.  I think what the OP is looking for is someone how as @MorgaFR suggested, is a hypocrite.

Comment: I would be careful deploying that in Central Scotland, where it would sound like 'ya bass' which is a colloquialism for 'you bastard'.

Answer (score -1):

Big talker.

From OED
/big talker  n.  (a) a person who speaks boastfully or extravagantly, a person who ‘talks big’;  (b) a person who is much given to talking, a great conversationalist.

1775   Gen. Election: Lett. between Friends I. xxiii. 235   These big talkers, as my brother observes, are generally the least doers./